# How to strategize your test automation?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I would like to get input on how to run automated smoke tests based on what developers check in. Currently, when there is a commit by devs the jenkins job gets built to build the code and smoke tests run to test the app. But smoke tests contains more than 50 tests. How would you design your automation so when there is a check in by devs, the automation only runs against the app features that could be affected by the new check in? Here is our flow: Dev checks in to git repo, jenkins job gets triggered through web hook and builds the app, once the build is done there is a downstream job to run the smoke tests. I would like to limit the smoke tests to only test the features that are affected by the new check in.

Comment: why not run them  all? How long do 50 tests take to run? What kinds of tests are these -- high level end-to-end tests or low level unit and integration tests?

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't want to run all of them because we have check ins about every 30 mins and running smoke tests which takes about 10 mins is kind of inefficient. But I don't want to take some tests out of the list of smokes either. Theses tests are straight happy path tests. No perf testing, only UI functionality and features.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which areas of your product might be affected but you can not be 100% sure. Don't rely on that. You don't want to have regressions with unknown source. They are extremely hard to triage and one of the best things about continuous integration is that each change or small amount of changes are tested separately and you know at each moment what is wrong with your app without spending many time on investigation. 10 minutes for a set of 50 tests is actually very good. Why don't think on **making them parallel** instead of reducing the test suit if the only problem about running the tests is the time consumed. I would prefer to speed up the test execution phase instead of decreasing the test suit.